# Google wallet integration in android app

Tags: android, android-pay

I am in way to develop an android app in which we can open google wallet for payment through credit card etc.

I want to integrate google wallet in my android app to launch on a button click.

Here is my scenario:

I have to options one is **Payment through credit card to another user account** like money transfer and payment on purchase of any item.

**Second is payment through online banking.**

Can we use google wallet for the above functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is no, you cannot use Google Wallet on Android for third party money transfers.
A Google Wallet transaction on Android can only take place between you (the merchant) and an user (the buyer).

Google Wallet is available on Android in two flavors.

**In-app Billing** - used to sell digital goods:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html

**Instant Buy for Android** - used to sell real goods and services:

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/android-overview/

Comment: hi... Mihai lonescu... pls provide me any usefull link if possible how to integrate google wallet in my app. Thanks....

Comment: https://developers.google.com/wallet/instant-buy/android/tutorial please check this url for integrating google wallet

Comment: @Mihai lonescu +1 to your answer. Please provide me some more links about Instant Buy for android

Comment: I recommend to start with the I/O codelab that has step-by-step instructions on how to integrate: https://io2014codelabs.appspot.com/static/codelabs/instant-buy/#1

The latest technical documentation is at:
https://developers.google.com/wallet/instant-buy/android/tutorial

Comment: @Mihai lonescu : 404 not found