# How to integrate Google Wallet in iOS App?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to integrate Google wallet in iOS app. Please help me with an idea.I have to find out how to integrate Google wallet to my iOS app.

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding of Google Wallet and what I believe you want to do with Google wallet this will not be possible.

See the following question relating to Google Wallet and Android - [Google wallet integration in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563128/google-wallet-integration-in-android-app)

The same rules will apply for Google Wallet within iOS - if anything it would be harder to do this in iOS than Android.